# Select data which not contains specific data in other table

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables:

```
+-------------------------+
| Domain                  |
+-------------------------+
| DomainID       int      |
| RegistryDate   date     |
+-------------------------+
```

And

```
+-------------------------+
| Annuity                 |
+-------------------------+
| AnnuityID      int      |
| DomainID       int      |
| Year           smallint |
+-------------------------+
```

In each table, I have these registry entries:

```
Domain:
1 | mysite.com      | 2014-02-10 |
2 | myecommerce.com | 2013-08-15 |

Annuity:
1 | 1 | 2014
2 | 1 | 2015
3 | 2 | 2013
4 | 2 | 2014
5 | 2 | 2015
```

I need to filter domains which doesn't have paid annuity for this year (2016) and has expired.

Example: If I run the query today (June, 9, 2016), my query results should filter `mysite.com` domain, but doesn't should filter `myecommerce.com` domain, because `mysite.com` has expired at February, 10, and the annuity for 2016 wasn't paid, while `myecommerce.com` will expire in August, 15.

I'm using MySQL. How can I write the SQL query?

Thank you!

Comment: There's no indicator in your tables for annuity being paid or unpaid. In your example, both "myecommerce.com" and "mysite.com" have entries for 2015.

Comment: If has a registry in Annuity for 2016, it indicates that 2016 was paid.

Comment: I'm sure that's what you meant :-) But your example data is in Annuity is currently: `1 | 1 | 2014`, `2 | 1 | 2015`, `3 | 2 | 2013`, `4 | 2 | 2014`, `5 | 2 | 2015`. There's no 2016 in there and both have 2015's.

Comment: Yes. Because "mysite.com" wasn't paid and "myecommerce.com" will due only in August, 15. Then it shouldn't have to be shown. Both was paid in 2015.

Comment: How do we know it's expired?

Comment: For example: we are in June, 9. So the "mysite.com" domain which was registered in February, 10, and doesn't have 2016 annuity registry, should be considered expired and unpaid.

Comment: The "myecommerce.com" domain doesn't should be considered expired, because it will due only in August, 15 and has 2015 annuity registry. Only at August, 16 it will be considered expired.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need to use a left outer join

```
SELECT d.id
FROM Domain d
LEFT OUTER JOIN Annuity a ON (d.id = a.DomainID AND a.Year = 2016)
WHERE a.id IS NULL
AND (MONTH(d.RegistryDate), DAY(d.RegistryDate)) < (MONTH(NOW()), DAY(NOW());
```

Comment: This works fine if I wish to show any domains which doesn't have a 2016 annuity paid. But I need to show only that domains which are due (doesn't have a 2016 annuity paid AND the due date was before today).

Comment: Added an additional clause to the `where`. I *think* tuple comparisons like this work in MySQL (I know they do in Postgresql), but if they don't, you can unpack the month/day comarisons.

Comment: It doesn't worked, but I removed the "day" filter and works for 2016. But I need it works for 2016 and 2015. I'll try a union query (even if it will be lazy). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this query is based on Andrew's answer. I want to post it on comment but I don't have enough rep.

```
SELECT * FROM Domain d LEFT OUTER JOIN Annuity a  
ON (d.DomainID = a.DomainID AND a.Year = LEFT(CURRENT_DATE, 4))
WHERE a.DomainID IS NULL AND CONCAT(LEFT(CURRENT_DATE, 4), right(d.RegistryDate, 6)) > CURRENT_DATE;
```

Comment: Can you explain the CURRENT_DATE before "Annuity a"? Thanks

Comment: Oopss, sorry it should be LEFT OUTER JOIN